# how install these dependecies on my hardhat project

Tags: hardhat

i am trying to create a hardhat project, and after i run the npx hardhat and follow prompts, it shows this;

###You need to install these dependencies to run the sample project:
npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^3.0.0"###

how to install these dependencies

i am trying to create a hardhat project, and after i run the npx hardhat and follow prompts, it shows this;

###You need to install these dependencies to run the sample project:
npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^3.0.0"###

I already have the nomic installed on vscode

Comment: thanks, pretty obvious i later realized

Answer (score 0):

The error message already tells you how to install them!

Go to the Hardhat project directory in the terminal and run the given command.

```
npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.17.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@^3.0.0"
```

Comment: SO, I have another issue ser, when I try to compile this, this error returns.

Comment: What errors are you getting this time?